# existing UITableView photo grid not rotating correctly?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, rotation, ipod

I am trying to make a basic photo grid, that is a "grid" of small "thumbnail" images, that when clicked go to a big version of the image. I am using a UITableView to accomplish this. My problem is that when I try adding rotation support I cant get the table to redraw the grid with an extra row of images.

Here's some of my code, PLEASE feel free to ask any question as I'm at my wits end on this one >:(

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        NSLog(@"portrait");
        for (int i=0; i < self.numberOfColumns; i++) {
            if (self.photoIndex < [self.photosArray count] || self.shouldReload==TRUE) {
                UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

                UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

                [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                switch (self.buttonNumber) {
                    case 1:
                        self.xCord=35.0f;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        self.xCord=213.25f;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        self.xCord=391.5f;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        self.xCord=569.75f;
                        self.buttonNumber=1;
                        break;
                }
                imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.xCord, 35.0f, 163.25f, 163.25f);
                imageButton.tag = self.photoIndex;
                imageButton.enabled=FALSE;
                imageButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

                if(self.buttonsArray.count < self.photosArray.count)[self.buttonsArray addObject:imageButton];

                if([self.isInternetAvailableClass isInternetAvailable]==YES)[self downloadImages:self.photoIndex];
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                [cell addSubview:imageButton];

                if(self.photoIndex < self.buttonsArray.count){
                if(![[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex:self.photoIndex] currentImage]){

                loadingActivityIndicator.center = imageButton.center;
                loadingActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=TRUE;

                }
                }
                 if(self.activityIndicatorArray.count < self.photosArray.count){

                     [self.activityIndicatorArray addObject:loadingActivityIndicator];
                     if([self.isInternetAvailableClass isInternetAvailable]==YES){

                         [loadingActivityIndicator startAnimating];   

                     }

                 }else{
                     if(self.photoIndex < self.buttonsArray.count){
                     [self.activityIndicatorArray replaceObjectAtIndex:self.photoIndex withObject:loadingActivityIndicator];

                     }
                 }


               [cell addSubview:loadingActivityIndicator];
                self.photoIndex++;
            }
        }

    return cell;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"landscape called!");
        for (int i=0; i < self.numberOfColumns; i++) {
            if (self.photoIndex < [self.photosArray count] || self.shouldReload==TRUE ){
                NSLog(@"inside landscape called!");
                UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

                UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

                [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                switch (self.buttonNumber) {
                    case 1:
                        self.xCord=37;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        self.xCord=230;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        self.xCord=423;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        self.xCord=616;
                        self.buttonNumber++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        self.xCord=809;
                        self.buttonNumber=1;
                        break;
                }
                imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.xCord, 35.0f, 163.25f, 163.25f);
                imageButton.tag = self.photoIndex;
                imageButton.enabled=FALSE;
                imageButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

                if(self.buttonsArray.count < self.photosArray.count){

                    [self.buttonsArray addObject:imageButton];
                }

                if([self.isInternetAvailableClass isInternetAvailable]==YES){

                [self downloadImages:self.photoIndex];
                }
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                [cell addSubview:imageButton];

                if(self.photoIndex < self.buttonsArray.count){
                if(![[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex:self.photoIndex] currentImage]){

                    loadingActivityIndicator.center = imageButton.center;
                    loadingActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=TRUE;
                }
            }
                if(self.activityIndicatorArray.count < self.photosArray.count){

                    [self.activityIndicatorArray addObject:loadingActivityIndicator];
                    if([self.isInternetAvailableClass isInternetAvailable]==YES){

                        [loadingActivityIndicator startAnimating];

                    }

                }else{
                    if(self.photoIndex < self.activityIndicatorArray.count){
                    [self.activityIndicatorArray replaceObjectAtIndex:self.photoIndex withObject:loadingActivityIndicator];
                    }
                }


                [cell addSubview:loadingActivityIndicator];
                self.photoIndex++;
            }
        }

        return cell;

    }
    if (self.shouldReload==TRUE)self.shouldReload=FALSE;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 205.0f;
}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.photosTableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    self.photosTableView.delegate=self;
    self.photosTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.photosTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.photosTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.photosTableView];

    self.isInternetAvailableClass = [[IsInternetAvailable alloc]init];
    self.buttonNumber=1;
    self.xCord=0.0f;
    self.downloadedImageNumber=0;
    self.buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.downloadedImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.activityIndicatorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.photosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.largePhotosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.imageOrderDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.refToDownloadedImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    self.unformattedPhotosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.appDelegate = (StereophotoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.shouldReload=FALSE;

    if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        self.numberOfColumns=4;
    }else{
        self.numberOfColumns=5;
    }

    self.photoIndex=0;
    self.errorImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewWillAppear:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceDidRotate) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [self loadImages];
    }
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.appDelegate.isSlideshowRunning=NO;
    self.appDelegate.PhotosPopoverSlideshowText = @"Start Slideshow";

    if([self.isInternetAvailableClass isInternetAvailable]==YES){

        if(self.isCommingFromNoNetworkConnectivity==YES){
            [self viewDidLoad];
        }
        if(self.photosTableView.isHidden==YES)[self.photosTableView setHidden:NO];
        self.isCommingFromNoNetworkConnectivity=NO;
    }else{

        if(self.photosTableView.isHidden==NO){

            [self.photosTableView setHidden:YES];

            self.isCommingFromNoNetworkConnectivity=YES;
        }
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"No Internet connection was detected! Please connect to the Internet and try again!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    for(NSURLConnection *connection in self.connectionsArray){
        [connection cancel];
    }
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return TRUE;
}
-(void)deviceDidRotate{
    self.photosTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        self.numberOfColumns=4;
    }else{
        self.numberOfColumns=5;
    }
    self.shouldReload=TRUE;
    [self.photosTableView reloadData];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.photosTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

}
```

thanks for ANY help!

Shredder

Comment: I haven't gone through the code, but a I correct in assuming that it works in landscape mode if you start in landscape mode, and it's only the changing of orientation that is problematic? If so, just call `[self.tableview reloadData]` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Personally, I use a UIScrollView for my gallery grid, and then on `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I just adjust the frames accordingly. But that's a more substantial rewrite.

Comment: Yes, If you start in lanscape mode it works fine its only if you start in portrait then rotate it. The problem is that if you call `[self.tableview reloadData]; ` after it has been loaded the if statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath cathes and doesent call the rest of the function unless you set self.photoIndex back to 0 which messes the activity indicators up.

Comment: Ok, I see you tried `reloadData`, but didn't notice that you had all of that conditional logic in there. Yeah, you just need to have a different solution for knowing whether an image has been downloaded or not. Relying on self.photoIndex is not the right solution. And creating new UIButtons regardless of whether the table view cell was created or was successfully dequeued is problematic, too. As is calling `viewDidLoad` from `viewWillAppear` (even if you're conditionally doing it based upon a change of network status). Bottom line, I'm seeing a ton of stuff here.

Comment: Shall we move this to chat (rather than doing detailed stuff in comments)? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14554/chat-b-w-rob-ryan-and-shredder2794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a table view is the wrong tool for a gallery. You're always going to go through some silliness to put multiple images in a single table view cell, you presumably aren't going to be using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` logic, etc. I'd suggest a `UIScrollView` instead (see example below).

But, if you were determined to use a table view, then `[self.tableView reloadData]` is the right solution. But your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has quite a few problems:

1. You should only create `UIButtons` if you're creating your cell. You'll have to take care, though, given your landscape v portrait orientation, of handling that properly. Not hard, but be careful.
2. You should decouple the caching of images with the loading of cells. They really are two different things, even though it might feel like they're awfully similar. Regardless, you definitely shouldn't be changing the basics populating of a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based upon whether the image was cached or not; it just changes where you get the image.
3. Unrelated to the problem at hand, but I would't hard code screen coordinates. I wouldn't be surprised to see new iOS devices with different resolutions over the coming months/years. Personally, I calculate how many images I can fit on the screen based upon how many thumbnails I can fit `self.view.frame.width` (you might use `cell.contentView.frame.width`).
4. Also probably unrelated to the problem here, I would never recommend calling `viewDidLoad` from `viewWillAppear`. If you want to have some common initialization routine that they both use, then maybe you can do that (but even that is a little sloppy), but given that `viewDidLoad` is calling `[super viewDidLoad]`, you'll end up calling that `super` method twice, and you don't know if iOS is cool with that. Probably not disasterous, but I can't imagine that it's a good idea.
5. Finally, also unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to use the notification center for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` because the standard `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will do that for us.

If you wanted to do a `UIScrollView` version of a gallery with lazy loading of images from a remote server, leveraging a cache for the thumbnails, detecting a tap on the images, etc. it might look like the following. I draw your attention to an absolute absence of any portrait/landscape logic (because it just looks at the dimensions of the scrollview), but it handles orientation changes perfectly well. I have not included, though, my code for populating `NSArray *imageUrlStrings` because that's obviously completely unique to a particular app, but you probably get the idea nonetheless. And there are all sorts of optimizations you could do (e.g. use `Reachability`), but this is a shell of a gallery that might do the job for you.

```
//  GalleryViewController.m

#import "GalleryViewController.h"
#import "ThumbnailCache.h"

#define IMAGE_WIDTH 76.0
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 76.0

@interface MyImage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property BOOL loading;
@property BOOL loaded;

@end

@implementation MyImage

// I find that I generally can get away with loading images in main queue using Documents
// cache, too, but if your images are not optimized (e.g. are large), or if you're supporting
// older, slower devices, you might not want to use the Documents cache in the main queue if
// you want a smooth UI. If this is the case, change kUseDocumentsCacheInMainQueue to NO and
// then use the Documents cache only in the background thread.

#define kUseDocumentsCacheInMainQueue YES

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
        _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [_view addSubview:_imageView];
        _loading = NO;
        _loaded = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadImage:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
{
    if (self.loading)
        return;

    self.loading = YES;

    ThumbnailCache *cache = [ThumbnailCache sharedManager];

    if (self.imageView.image == nil)
    {
        UIImage *imageFromCache = [cache objectForKey:self.urlString useDocumentsCache:kUseDocumentsCacheInMainQueue];
        if (imageFromCache)
        {
            if (self.activityIndicator)
            {
                [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                self.activityIndicator = nil;
            }

            self.imageView.image = imageFromCache;
            self.loading = NO;
            self.loaded = YES;
            return;
        }

        if (self.activityIndicator == nil)
        {
            self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
            [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
        }
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            if (self.loading)
            {
                UIImage *image = nil;

                // only requery cache for Documents cache if we didn't do so in the main queue

                if (!kUseDocumentsCacheInMainQueue)
                    image = [cache objectForKey:self.urlString useDocumentsCache:YES];

                // if we haven't gotten the image yet, retrieve it from the remote server

                if (!image)
                {
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];

                    if (data)
                    {
                        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [cache setObject:image forKey:self.urlString data:data];
                    }
                }

                // now update the UI in the main queue

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (self.loading)
                    {
                        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        self.activityIndicator = nil;
                        self.imageView.image = image;
                        self.loading = NO;
                        self.loaded = YES;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

- (void)unloadImage
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, self.urlString);

    // remove from imageview, but not cache

    self.imageView.image = nil;

    self.loaded = NO;
    self.loading = NO;
}

@end


@interface GalleryViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_myImages;
    dispatch_queue_t _queue;
}
@end

@implementation GalleryViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (_queue)
        dispatch_release(_queue);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // this is not strictly necessary because `NSCache` will automatically
    // evict objects in low memory situations; it will not, though
    // remove items when you try to simulate a low memory situation
    // in the simulator, but it really will empty the cache when
    // memory really runs low
    //
    // ThumbnailCache *cache = [ThumbnailCache sharedManager];
    // [cache removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    _queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.robertmryan.imageloader", NULL);

    [self loadImages];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandler:)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    NSUInteger imagesPerRow = (self.view.frame.size.width / IMAGE_WIDTH);
    CGFloat imageMargin = (self.view.frame.size.width - (IMAGE_WIDTH * imagesPerRow)) / (imagesPerRow + 1.0);

    NSUInteger row = 0;
    NSUInteger col = -1;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_myImages count]; i++)
    {
        col++;
        if (col >= imagesPerRow)
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        MyImage *myImage = [_myImages objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame = myImage.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = imageMargin + (imageMargin + IMAGE_WIDTH) * col;
        frame.origin.y = imageMargin + (imageMargin + IMAGE_HEIGHT) * row;
        myImage.view.frame = frame;
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, (row + 1) * (IMAGE_HEIGHT + imageMargin) + imageMargin);

    [self displayVisibleImages:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    _myImages = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self displayVisibleImages:NO];
}

- (void)appDidBecomeActive
{
    [self displayVisibleImages:YES];
}

- (void)displayVisibleImages:(BOOL)forceLoad
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect  contentFrame  = self.scrollView.bounds;
    contentFrame.origin = contentOffset;

    for (MyImage *myImage in _myImages)
    {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(contentFrame, myImage.view.frame))
        {
            // if the image is visible, then make sure it's loaded

            if (!myImage.loaded || forceLoad)
                [myImage loadImage:_queue];
        }
        else
        {
            // if not, go ahead and unload it to conserve memory

            if (myImage.loaded || myImage.loading)
                [myImage unloadImage];
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self displayVisibleImages:NO];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGFloat version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (version < 5.0)
        [self viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return TRUE;
}

- (void)tapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.scrollView];

    for (MyImage *myImage in _myImages)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImage.view.frame, location))
            NSLog(@"Tapped in image %1d", myImage.view.tag);
    }
}

- (void)loadImages
{

    NSArray *imageUrlStrings = [self loadImageUrls];
    _myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSUInteger imagesPerRow = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width / IMAGE_WIDTH);
    CGFloat imageMargin = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (IMAGE_WIDTH * imagesPerRow)) / (imagesPerRow + 1.0);

    NSInteger row = 0;
    NSInteger col = -1;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [imageUrlStrings count]; i++)
    {
        col++;
        if (col >= imagesPerRow)
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        MyImage *myImage = [[MyImage alloc] init];
        myImage.urlString = [imageUrlStrings objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame = myImage.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = imageMargin + (imageMargin + IMAGE_WIDTH) * col;
        frame.origin.y = imageMargin + (imageMargin + IMAGE_HEIGHT) * row;
        myImage.view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:myImage.view];
        myImage.view.tag = i;

        [_myImages addObject:myImage];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, (row + 1) * (IMAGE_HEIGHT + imageMargin) + imageMargin);
}

@end
```

My `ThumbnailCache` is just a simple `NSCache` singleton object. (Whether you implement this as a singleton, is up to you; you don't have to but it's convenient given the nature of my apps.) I've updated this to encapsulate a secondary `Documents` cache (thus you're retrieving images from a remote server, cached in both the `NSCache` object for optimal performance, and secondarily cached in the `Documents` folder if you want to save subsequent invocations of the program from needing to re-retrieve the images from the server, giving you a persistent cache across sessions). This theoretically could (should?) be optimized to purge the `Documents` folder of images that haven't been used for a long time, but I'll leave that for others to implement.

```
//
//  ThumbnailCache.h
//
//  Created by Robert Ryan on 7/17/12.
//  Modified 8/9/12 to support secondary Documents-based cache.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThumbnailCache : NSCache

+ (id)sharedManager;

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key useDocumentsCache:(BOOL)useDocumentsCache;
- (void)setObject:(UIImage *)image forKey:(id)key data:(NSData *)data;

@end
```

and

```
//
//  ThumbnailCache.m
//
//  Created by Robert Ryan on 7/17/12.
//  Modified 8/9/12 to support secondary Documents-based cache.
//

#import "ThumbnailCache.h"

@implementation ThumbnailCache

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.name = @"Thumbnail cache";
    }

    return self;
}

+ (id)sharedManager 
{
    static ThumbnailCache *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key
{
    return [self objectForKey:key useDocumentsCache:YES];
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key useDocumentsCache:(BOOL)useDocumentsCache
{
    // This is a variation of the standard objectForKey method which takes an additional
    // parameter, useDocumentsCache, which will tell this to also check the Documents
    // cache or not. This is a subtle refinement in case you don't want your main queue
    // to use the Documents cache. Generally, if you're dealing with optimized images,
    // this is not necessary, but if you're dealing with large images, this permutation
    // can be useful.

    // first, just try to get the image from the NSCache

    id result = [super objectForKey:key];

    // if successful (or if we don't want to look in the Documents cache), then just return.

    if (result || !useDocumentsCache)
        return result;

    // otherwise, if we didn't find it in the NSCache and we want to look in our Documents
    // cache, then let's do so

    NSString *path = [self pathInDocumentCache:key];

    if (!result && path)
    {
        // get the data from the remote server

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        if (data)
        {
            // and if we found it, save it in our NSCache

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (image)
                [self setObject:image forKey:key];

            return image;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

- (void)setObject:(UIImage *)image forKey:(id)key data:(NSData *)data
{
    // This is a variation of the standard setObject:forKey which takes an additional NSData.
    // The notion is that our cache stores UIImage objects (to save the theoretical overhead,
    // if any, of loading image data into a NSData and then into a UIImage ... I wouldn't be
    // surprised if Apple did some cool optimization of UIImage objects, though I don't know),
    // so if we want to write our image file, but don't want to convert the UIImage back to
    // a NSData, then let's just take the original NSData as a parameter.

    // save the object in the NSCache

    [super setObject:image forKey:key];

    // now let's also save the NSData in our Documents-based cache

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *path = [self pathInDocumentCache:key];

    if (path && ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        // let's create the folder if we need to

        NSString *folder = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder])
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

        // and let's write the NSData to that folder

        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pathInDocumentCache:(NSString *)key
{
    if (![key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_cache"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:key];

    return [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url relativePath]];
}

@end
```

I'd be surprised if there weren't some great publicly available gallery classes, too, but if you wanted to roll your own, the above is a possibility.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! As I am new to iOS development I didn't know any if this. Again, thank you!

Comment: I've had a lot of stuff on my plate with school starting and stuff and I'm only now getting around to playing with this code. It works great except that when you rotate the device the grid does not re-draw to include any more(or less) "columns." What I mean is if I have 7 images in the grid, 5 on the first row and 2 on the second row, when I rotate the device the grid stays the same,that is to say there are still 5 images in the top row and 2 in the second.READ NEXT COMMENT

Comment: Not trying to be a help vampire but how would I go about setting it up where when you rotate the device it redraws the number of images to match the available landscape?

Comment: This view is one of four root view controllers in a tab bar. I haven't done any diagnostic stuff yet. I will let you know what happens when I do. And really, I can't thank you enough for helping me with this.

Comment: I got it figured out. The problem was that I had placed the ScrollView into the view controller via storyboard and that was somehow interfering with me setting its frame in code when the view loads. Now that I am creating the scroll view via code it works great! I can't explain how thankful I am that you helped me with this as I was just about to give up before this post!

Comment: If its not too much trouble could you give me a basic example of how to save the images to documents to serve as a cache?

Comment: @Shredder2794 There are several ways to do this, but I have updated my answer with one possible solution, encapsulating the `Documents` secondary cache right in the `ThumbnailCache` class. Essentially, all I'm doing is writing the image to the `Documents` folder when you add an object to the `ThumbnailCache` in `setObject:forKey` and conditionally checking the Documents folder in `objectForKey`.